# Cannot receive and display props in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Im my MERN application a have a problem on frontend side. When I make a GET-request on backend on `/params` address, I can get a json-object in response:

```
current: 2
date: "2021-10-01T07:00:32.524Z"
power: 7.2
soc: 100
temperature: 20.5
voltage: 3.6
__v: 0
_id: "6156b21021e67919047727c7"
```

Whether the object is actually received and GET_PARAMS action is dispatched, I can make sure using `console.log()` in reducer file:

```
import {
    GET_PARAMS,
    PARAMS_ERROR,
    CLEAR__PARAMS
} from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
    params: null,
    loading: true,
    exist: true,
    error: {}
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
    const { type, payload } = action; 
    
    switch (type) {
        case GET_PARAMS: 
            return {
                ...state,
                params: payload,
                loading: false,
                exist: true
            };
        case PARAMS_ERROR:
            return {
                ...state,
                error: payload,
                loading: false,
                params: null,
                exist: false
            };
        case CLEAR__PARAMS:
            return {
                ...state,
                params: null,
                loading: false,
                exist: true
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

But when I run the application, I can see only empty placeholders in React component because of `undefined` values of props:

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Spinner from '../layout/Spinner';
import NotFound from '../layout/NotFound';
import { getParams } from '../../actions/params';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
const Params = ({getParams, params: { voltage, current, power, soc, temperature, date }, loading, exist, 
    auth }) => {
    console.log(voltage);  //undefined

    useEffect(() => {
        getParams();
    }, [getParams]);

    return (
        <Fragment>
           <h1>ESP8266 Aspil Web Server</h1>
                        <table className="table">
                           <tbody>
                           <tr>
                                <td className="hide-sm"><h3>Time: </h3> </td>
                                <td className="hide-sm"><h3 id="time">{date}</h3></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td className="hide-sm"><h3>Voltage: </h3></td>
                                <td className="hide-sm"><h3 id="voltage">{voltage} V</h3></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td className="hide-sm"><h3>Current: </h3></td>
                                <td className="hide-sm"><h3 id="current">{current} A</h3></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td className="hide-sm"><h3>Power: </h3></td>
                                <td className="hide-sm"><h3 id="power">{power} W</h3></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td className="hide-sm"><h3>SOC: </h3></td>
                                <td className="hide-sm"><h3 id="soc">{soc}%</h3></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td className="hide-sm"><h3>Temperature: </h3></td>
                                <td className="hide-sm"><h3 id="temperature">{temperature} oC</h3></td>
                            </tr>
                           </tbody>
                        </table>
        </Fragment>
    )
};

Params.propTypes = {
    params: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    getParams: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    params: state.params,
    auth: state.auth,
    loading: state.loading,
    exist: state.exist
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getParams })(Params);
```

Why is it going wrong?

Comment: Do you have any log of the `params` object without destructing? I assume you're using something like Redux thunk for your asynchronous actions.

Comment: connect(mapStateToProps, { getParams })(Params) this should be connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Params) as the second param is for the function to dispatch and you are not dispatching anything, also plz once console params , check whether its coming or not check its type aswell it can be of string so the destruct may not work

Comment: @AyushiKeshri `getParams` is dispatched in the `useEffect` hook.

Comment: Can you update your question to include ***all*** of your reducer code so that we may see what the value of `state.params` may be? What is the initial state value? What is the value of `payload` in the reducer function?

Comment: I'm a little surprised you're not seeing a "cannot access X of null" error since the initial `state.params` value is null and you are destructuring from it. You are also console logging as an unintentional side-effect, move it to an `useEffect` hook.

Comment: Can you edit your question with your `action` code too?

Answer (score 2):

To display the data in your table you should use `.map()` as you are fetching data from backend. So with **.map()** it is going to take all you data and individually it will display the feilds that you want to.

SO I am just assuming you have code I am writing below.

Data returned from the backend:

```
current: 2
date: "2021-10-01T07:00:32.524Z"
power: 7.2
soc: 100
temperature: 20.5
voltage: 3.6
__v: 0
_id: "6156b21021e67919047727c7"
```

`action`

```
export const getAllData = () => async dispatch => {
    const response = await axios.get("/params");
    dispatch({ type: GET_PARAMS, payload: response.data });
};
```

`reducer`

```
import {
    GET_PARAMS,
    PARAMS_ERROR,
    CLEAR__PARAMS
} from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
    params: null,
    loading: true,
    exist: true,
    error: {}
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
    const { type, payload } = action; 
    
    switch (type) {
        case GET_PARAMS: 
            return {
                ...state,
                params: payload,
            };
        case PARAMS_ERROR:
            return {
                ...state,
                error: payload,
                loading: false,
                params: null,
                exist: false
            };
        case CLEAR__PARAMS:
            return {
                ...state,
                params: null,
                loading: false,
                exist: true
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

As I have no idea how you are getting data from backend to front end. Don't know what is the value of `this.props` so I am assuming its more or less code below.

`component`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableContainer from '@material-ui/core/TableContainer';
import { getAllData} from "./actions";


class Params extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      skip: 0,
      limit: 10,
      pageNumber: 0,
      value: ''
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
     this.props.getAllData();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div/>
        <Container>
          <TableContainer>
            <Table aria-label="enhanced table">
              <TableHead>
                <TableRow>
                  <TableCell>Time</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>Voltage</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>Current</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>Power</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>SOC</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>Temperature</TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              </TableHead>
              <TableBody>
                {this.props.params.map((busObj, index) => {
                  return (
                    <TableRow>
                      <TableCell> {busObj.date} </TableCell>
                      <TableCell >{busObj.voltage}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell>{busObj.current}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell >{busObj.power}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell>{busObj.soc}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell>{busObj.temperature}</TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                  )
                })}
              </TableBody>
            </Table>
          </TableContainer>
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Params.propTypes = {
    params: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    getParams: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    params: state.params,
    auth: state.auth,
    loading: state.loading,
    exist: state.exist
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getParams })(Params);
```

This can be more or less what you want. I hope this is what your looking for.